# Unity crashes every time when it reloads Script Assemblies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode to modify the C # code, or click the Run button, unity reloads the script assembly. This is causing unity to get stuck.

I tried to delete unnecessary packages in the Package Manager and modify the playback mode options. But it didn't work.

I don´t want unity be stuck when reloading the assembly.

Comment: Your header says "crashes" but your description indicates a hang or a delay. Can you please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Unity will freeze for a while when loading scripts. If it takes longer than say 2 minutes for a small project, thats a problem. However, it could also be that your computer is underpowered. You can disable auto reloading assemblies by going into edit/preferences/general/autorefresh. If you have many packages that aren’t compiled beforehand, that could also be a problem. I would recommend just being patient. If you need to, you can pay for unity cloud compilation.